# Facebook user integration

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am having a problem in my facebook code. Currently, what I want to do is allow someone to set up a space in my app, and upload a file that can then be viewed by their friends. I cannot find any reasonable way to do this. Is it currently possible to allow Person A to view Person B's data within my app? Please, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to store uploaded files on your own server, and associate those files with the uploading Facebook user account. When a friend visits looking for files, you can query Facebook for their friend relationships to determine which files to display to them.

Comment: Essentially, this is what I am already doing. I have written the code to upload, store and display certain images. However, I can find no parameter in the facebook api that differentiates between one user viewing a specific page, and another. For instance, I am able to get the access token of Friend A and the access token of User B, but I am not able to get my code to determine that Friend A is viewing User B's page. This is because facebook allows one static URL to be loaded within the Iframe

Comment: Thus, if Friend B clicks any link to be directed to the application, he gets www.site.com/app.php and not necessarily anything to determine that he actually clicked on User B's profile in the page.

Comment: You can display a list of the viewer's friends and have them select which friend they want to view the files of. If you're looking for an  automatic selection then I think you'll need to reword your question and define a specific problem

Comment: I need to be able to send a message from a user to one of his friends with a URL, which the friend can then click and see ONLY the information uploaded by the user that sent him the link

Comment: Insert something that identifies the user into the URL. When the user's friend visits it, you can identify the user and retrieve whatever you're storing. Since that solution is fairly straightforward I'll assume I've misunderstood what you're looking for. If you can clearly define your problem, show what you've attempted and why it doesn't work, then we can get somewhere :)